# Black UINavigationBar but statusBar stays black

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I want to go from a black statusbar to a white statusbar.

This is my vc structure: `A -> nav controller -> B`

Somehow I can't seem to set it to white, whatever I try. I tried the simplest solution of setting the navigationController's style to black, but that won't work either!! I'm stuck on this for hours, and I've even tried to a custom extension on `UINavigationController` but somehow the statusbar seems really unresponsive. For reference, this is my nav/statusbar like:

[image]

This is my setup in VC B:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent; 
[self preferredStatusBarStyle];
```

Am I missing something big? How can the statusbar be black when the navbar is black too?

Answer (score -1):

Open the "info.plist" file.
Add a new item with "Status bar style" as the key and "Opaque black style" as the value.

This should solve your problem

2nd Solution:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

You can see different statusBarStyle in the above function. Call this in your viewController

Comment: I can't do that as I need a non-opaque one elsewhere in my project, not including this value in the plist means just that i should be able to set it per vc, as i've set that value to be vc independent.

Comment: I'm sorry but as I said in my question i've already tried a lot of those things. I'm looking for an answer that tells me how this is possible and how to fix it, and *why*. Not some random answer copied-pasted from another so question.